# Python script suddenly throwing timeout exceptions

Tags: python, web-crawler, httprequest

I have a Python script that downloads product feeds from multiple affiliates in different ways. This didn't give me any problems until last Wednesday, when it started throwing all kinds of timeout exceptions from different locations.

Examples: Here I connect with a FTP service:

```
ftp = FTP(host=self.host)
```

threw:

```
Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Crawler\src\Crawlers\LDLC.py", line 23, in main
    ftp = FTP(host=self.host)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.py", line 138, in connect
    self.welcome = self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.py", line 215, in getresp
    resp = self.getmultiline()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.py", line 201, in getmultiline
    line = self.getline()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\ftplib.py", line 186, in getline
    line = self.file.readline(self.maxline + 1)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
timeout: timed out
```

Or downloading an XML File :

```
xmlFile = urllib.URLopener()
        xmlFile.retrieve(url, self.feedPath + affiliate + "/" + website + '.' + fileType)
        xmlFile.close()
```

throws:

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Crawler\src\Crawlers\FeedCrawler.py", line 106, in save
    xmlFile.retrieve(url, self.feedPath + affiliate + "/" + website + '.' + fileType)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib.py", line 240, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib.py", line 346, in open_http
    errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 1139, in getreply
    response = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 1067, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
IOError: [Errno socket error] timed out
```

These are just two examples but there are other methods, like authenticate or other API specific methods where my script throws these timeout errors. It never showed this behavior until Wednesday. Also, it starts throwing them at random times. Sometimes at the beginning of the crawl, sometimes later on. My script has this behavior on both my server and my local machine. I've been struggling with it for two days now but can't seem to figure it out.

This is what I know might have caused this:

On Wednesday one affiliate script broke down with the following error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)>
```

I didn't change anything to my script but suddenly it stopped crawling that affiliate and threw that error all the time where I tried to authenticate. I looked it up and found that is was due to an OpenSSL error (where did that come from). I fixed it by adding the following before the authenticate method:

```
if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
                ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Little did I know, this was just the start of my problems... At that same time, I changed from Python 2.7.8 to Python 2.7.9. It seems that this is the moment that everything broke down and started throwing timeouts.

I tried changing my script in endless ways but nothing worked and like I said, it's not just one method that throws it. Also I switched back to Python 2.7.8, but this didn't do the trick either. Basically everything that makes a request to an external source can throw an error.

Final note: My script is multi threaded. It downloads product feeds from different affiliates at the same time. It used to run 10 threads per affiliate without a problem. Now I tried lowering it to 3 per affiliate, but it still throws these errors. Setting it to 1 is no option because that will take ages. I don't think that's the problem anyway because it used to work fine.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Does it returns any error code? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes

Comment: Sometimes a 403 Forbidden, but that's because we're not allowed to get product feed data for that website anymore but it's still in our product feed list.

Comment: Python 2.7.9 enabled proper SSL verification by default. This probably caused your SSL problems. The other problems simply look like network problems, either on your or on the server side. Check if you can access these location without your script from the same host.

Comment: They're all accessible without the script.